# Set timeout to a PHP function

Tags: php, linux, bash, function, timeout

I have this script

```
<?php
function get_reverse_dns($Ip)
{
    $result = exec("nslookup -n ".escapeshellarg($Ip)." | grep 'name = '");
    if(strpos($result,"name =") === false)
    {
        return "NO REVERSE";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = trim($result);
        $ExplodedResult = explode("name =",$result);
        $ExplodedResult[1] = trim($ExplodedResult[1]);
        $ReverseDns = trim($ExplodedResult[1],".");
        return $ReverseDns;
    }
}
?>
```

that gives me the reverse dns, now the problem is that sometimes, an IP can have a really long delay, and i want that this script to check it the IP can be "looked up", and if 5 seconds passed and this is not happening, then `return false`

How can i make that?

I have tried in linux

```
nslookup --timeout 5 1.1.1.1 | grep 'name = '
timeout 5 nslookup 1.1.1.1 | grep 'name = '
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use dig:
dig -x ${ip} +time=5 +tries=1 +retry=0 +short

This command will only return the IP address so it will simplify your parsing bit.

Comment: gives me error dig -x ${"34.33.44.53"} +time=5 +tries=1 +retry=0 +short
-bash: ${"34.33.44.53"}: bad substitution

Comment: ${} is a way to call a variable. Take off the "${ }" if you are going to put the IP address in directly.

dig -x 34.33.44.53 +time=5 +tries=1 +retry=0 +short

Answer (score 0):

You want to check `man nslookup` that will give you that the command should be:

```
nslookup -timeout 5 1.1.1.1 | grep 'name = '
```

You have one too many -'s

Comment: i see that, i know, but if i put any IP there, freezes and do not do anything ..., not even good ips that were looked up in 1 second ...